# Android: Вылетает AsyncTask

Tags: android, java

Вот класс.

```
class ShowBar extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private  boolean today = true;
    private Context context_dialog;

    public ShowBar(Context context, boolean day)
    {
       context_dialog = context;
        today = day;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog =
                ProgressDialog.show
                        (context_dialog
                                , "Подождите идёт загрузка"
                                , "Загрузка завершена", true);

        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        long result = 0;

        FootballView football = new FootballView();
        if (today)
            {
                football.getMatches();
            }else{
                football.getLastMatches();
            }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Вот так вызываю его из Активити:

```
ShowBar bar = new ShowBar(getApplicationContext(),true);
              bar.execute();
```

При исполнении этого кода приложение вылетает.
З.Ы. Метод getMatches связан с Интернетом.
Может тут какие-то подводные камни или я что-то не то написал.

Comment: "Вылетает" -- это не очень хорошее описание. Что происходит? Исключение? Какое, какой текст, в какой строчке? Думаете, мы сами должны догадаться? Если хотите ответ, вы должны сотрудничать, мы за вас задачу не решим.

Comment: А не пытаетесь ли в потом этот FootballView использовать в основном потоке? Что у вас result хранится?

Comment: Лог в студию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе doInBackground() не должно быть никаких вызовов, связанных с потоком UI(создание вью, использование их контекста и прочего). Для анимации прогресса и доступа к потоку UI(проще говоря, к пользовательскому интерфейсу) есть метод onProgressUpdate()
класса AsyncTask.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

И как вам уже подметили нужно выкладывать сообщения об ошибках, иначе это гадание на кофейной гуще.